# LibGDX app refused at AppStore for not including NSCalendarsUsageDescription

Tags: ios, libgdx, app-store-connect, robovm

I finally got to deploy my app for iPhone, and now that I uploaded to iTunes Connect I'm getting this message from Apple:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "App name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

So either I need to add the `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` key, but I don't know why LibGDX is attempting to access user's calendar, or somehow I should remove the code that access this resources that I'm not using.

Anybody has solved this? I'm using RoboVM to deploy for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the key in your info.plist . If LibGDX tries to access the calender an alert view will pop up with the text you entered for that key. So after adding the key just go through the whole app once and check if you get a alert anywhere. If not then you can keep any value for the key. If you do see the alert try to identify why its trying to access the calender and update the key value accordingly.